# Indexing a derived [ElasticType] only serializes the base class' properties

Tags: c#, nest

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why Nest is only serializing the below base class' properties when indexing an instance, even though I am telling it to index the derived class.

The base class:

```
[ElasticType(Name = "activity")]
public class Activity
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(OptOut = true)]
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp
    {
        get { return DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(TimestampAsString, "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime(); }
        set { TimestampAsString = value.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"); }
    }

    [Obsolete("Use Timestamp, instead.")]
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "timestamp")]
    public string TimestampAsString { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "application")]
    public string Application { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "application_version")]
    public string ApplicationVersion { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(OptOut = true)]
    public IPAddress RemoteIpAddress
    {
        get { return IPAddress.Parse(RemoteIpAddressAsString); }
        set { RemoteIpAddressAsString = value.ToString(); }
    }

    [Obsolete("Use RemoteIpAddress, instead.")]
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "remote_ip_address")]
    public string RemoteIpAddressAsString { get; set; }
}
```

The derived class:

```
private class SearchCountsRetrievedActivity : Activity
{
    [ElasticProperty(OptOut = true)]
    public PunctuationlessGuid? PrincipalIdentityId
    {
        set { PrincipalIdentityIdAsString = value; }
    }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "principal_identity_id")]
    public string PrincipalIdentityIdAsString { get; set; }
}
```

My index wrapper method:

```
public Task IndexActivityAsync<TActivity>(TActivity activity)
    where TActivity : Activity
{
    return _client.IndexAsync(activity);
}
```

No matter what I do, the serialized JSON sent over the wire only includes the `Activity` class' properties. What I've tried:

- Making the derived classes public
- Adding `[ElasticType]` to the derived classes
- Inspecting the Nest source code (this is very difficult as the source code is very complex, and the NuGet package I'm referencing, even though it's the latest one, appears to be not forward-compatible with the latest source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the underlying default JSON serializer does *not* serialize properties with a `null` value. In my case, my property values were `null`, so that's why they weren't being serialized. The serializer works properly when values are not `null`.